# Compare two unnormalized density functions given the values at samples

Tags: density-function, similarities

I have the density values of two unnormalized density functions $p$ and $q$ at 2000 points: $\mathbf{p} = (p(x_1), p(x_2), \dots p(x_{2000}))$, $\mathbf{q} = (q(x_1), q(x_2), \dots q(x_{2000}))$.

Now I would like to find the similarity between $p$ and $q$. Could you suggest how I should do it?

Thanks.

**Update**.

I am considering a similarity score by Monte Carlo approximation of KL divergence as following, do you think it is correct?

$KL = \int_{\Omega} \bar{p}(x) \log\frac{\bar{p}(x)}{\bar{q}(x)}dx = \frac{| \Omega |}{2000} \sum_{i = 1}^{2000}\bar{p}(x_i)\log\frac{\bar{p}(x_i)}{\bar{q}(x_i)}$

where $\bar{p}(x)$ and $\bar{q}(x)$ are normalized density functions from $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ and $\Omega$ is the domain.

$\bar{p}(x_i)$ and $\bar{q}(x_i)$ can be found, again by Monte Carlo approximation:

$\bar{p}(x_i) = \frac{p(x_i)}{\int_{\Omega}p(x)dx} = \frac{p(x_i)}{\frac{| \Omega |}{2000} \sum_{i = 1}^{2000}p(x_i)}$

$\bar{q}(x_i) = \frac{q(x_i)}{\int_{\Omega}q(x)dx} = \frac{q(x_i)}{\frac{| \Omega |}{2000} \sum_{i = 1}^{2000}q(x_i)}$

Replacing these values into the KL formulation, I would have

$KL = \sum_{i = 1}^{2000}  \frac{p(x_i)}{\sum_{i = 1}^{2000}p(x_i)} \log \frac{p(x_i)/\sum_{i = 1}^{2000}p(x_i)}{q(x_i)/\sum_{i = 1}^{2000}q(x_i)}$

(all the terms $\frac{| \Omega |}{2000}$ are cancelled).

My concern is that I use the same samples for both $KL$ calculation and density normalization. Would that make the approximation biased?

Comment: what do you mean by 'similarity' there?

Comment: I meant something like KL divergence, for example. I can't use KL divergence directly as I only have the density values at some samples; and these values are not normalized

Comment: That's an interesting problem! I would suggest resorting to a non-parametric estimate of $p$ and $q$, using the $p(x_i)$ and $q(X_i)$ as weights, e.g. $$\hat{p}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{2000} p(x_i) K(x-x_i)\Big/\sum_{i=1}^{2000} p(x_i)$$ and $$\hat{q}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{2000} q(x_i) K(x-x_i)\Big/\sum_{i=1}^{2000} q(x_i)$$where $K$ is an arbitrary kernel.

Comment: Thanks @Xi'an! $x_i$ are uniformly sampled from a domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by using **exploratory approach** in a form of [quantile-quantile (Q-Q) plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) and [kernel density plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation). Producing a Q-Q plot and, especially, a kernel density plot for your data set allows to perform a preliminary visual comparison of the corresponding *probability density functions (PDFs)*.

After that, you can use **analytical approach** to compare PDFs. Since you already have PDFs, there need to perform *distribution fitting*, which leaves the only step to execute testing *goodness-of-fit (GoF)*. If your data is not discrete, you can use *Kolmogorov-Smirnov*, *Anderson-Darling* or *Lilliefors* tests, otherwise those are not applicable to discrete distributions. However, fortunately, *chi-square GoF test* is applicable to both continuous and discrete distributions and in R is a matter of calling `stats::chisq.test()` function.

You can find useful a nice R-based [introductory paper](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf), relevant to the topic. A more detailed and comprehensive description of the topic of distribution comparison can be found in the book ["Comparing Distributions"](http://www.springer.com/statistics/book/978-0-387-92709-1), published by Springer (contains R-based example code as well).

Comment: Thanks! I am a bit unclear about what you meant by distribution fitting. The fact is I already have the distribution functions $p$ and $q$, just unnormalized. Do you mean I should use $p(x_i)$ and $q(x_i)$ as weights and fit new (normalized) density functions to $(x_1, x_2, \dots x_2000)$?

Comment: @mushin: You're welcome! You're right - distribution fitting is not applicable in this case, it was an accidental leftover from one of my earlier questions, where it made sense. I will remove the distribution fitting part. I think that the exploratory and GoF parts are still applicable and valid.

Comment: I'd like to know why this was down voted.

Comment: @ssdecontrol: I'm a bit curious about that, too. But, I think that my answer was downvoted, because it originally contained part on distribution fitting, which is not relevant in this case. I've removed that part.